# Communication between JFrames

Tags: java

I have two frames, Frame A and Frame B. Now, how the frame A will know when a button on Frame B is pressed?

Comment: Frame A won't know, Frame B has to notify this to Frame A somewhere.

Comment: Are they in the same class file?

Comment: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/597657)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't. I would consider a design pattern such as mvc: http://tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/model-view-controller-explained/

You need to have some sort of background construction to allow for the jFrames to communicate. MVC allows changes in the information for one jFrame to affect another. It's a little conceptually complex but appears to be a generally accepted form for creating user interfaces. There are a lot of resources out there to help you learn the correct form

Comment: yes MVC is usually the way people go with something like this. Frame A would notify via an ActionListener the Controller (class), which then decides what to do with the action notification, and if appropriate, forwards it off to Frame B to perform some function.Think of the Controller as the Traffic Guard for your program.

Comment: Design pattern is the correct term. thanks for the edit. And yes snakeDoc good elaboration